# Passing along data with request

Tags: go, mux

Say we have some auth middleware:

```
router.Use(auth);
```

and that looks like:

```
func auth(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok && token.Valid {
        var user User
        mapstructure.Decode(claims, &user)
        return next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    } 

     json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Exception{Message: "Invalid authorization token"})

    })
}
```

my question is - if we decode the JWT claims into user, how can I reference that user in other middleware functions. Using Node.js Express I can just pin the user to the request object. Is there some way to do this with Golang?

The only way I would know how to do that would be to create a map, mapping the request to a user. But then to clean up the map I would have to have some hook that could delete the map entry once the response for that request was sent.